# Will chat be searchable?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, chat

Will relevant chats be listed when performing a search from the top of a meta stackoverflow page?

Will there be a way to limit this just to active chats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chat already is searchable, but you have to do it on chat.meta.stackoverflow.com.

http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/search

You can limit it to a specific chat room by adding `room={roomnumber}` to the URL.  You can also specify the user.

Comment: The search entry on the http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/ page seems to only search chat room titles and descriptions.  While useful, this was confusing at first.  Should there be a link to the /search page to help with this distinction?

Answer (score 2):

When searching on the parent site? An interesting possibility. One to discuss, I suspect.

Comment: I guess this brings up the [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57435/is-chat-for-general-discussion) of whether or not chat is just for meta discussion.

Comment: Please, no. Its already hard enough to find things with search, don't flood the results with chat logs

Answer (score 1):

Yes, chat shows up in Google search, as all chats are public by default.

Only the transcripts are indexed, though.

For example:

http://www.google.com/search?q=%22seeding+is+nice+and+all,+but+it+feels+too+much+like+rep+whoring%22