# Is chat for general discussion?

Tags: discussion, chat, search

When chat is added to the various stackexchange sites is it to be used for general discussion of the topic, or only for meta discussion?

This is relevant to how [search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57431/will-chat-be-searchable) should work with respect to chats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is for general discussion of the topic. As I understand, there will be 3 domains to each site:

http://example.com <- the SE 2.0 site
http://meta.example.com <- the place for people to discuss the site
http://chat.example.com <- the place for people to hang out

http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com is the exception*, as MSO is not really a meta-site for Stack Overflow, but the meta site for Stack Exchange as a whole.

*i.e. I do not believe there will be any other *chat.meta.example.com* sites

Comment: Chat is practically meta anyway, you're not actually going to use chat to ask questions.